# $v$, $w$ variant with stix package

Tags: math-mode, fonts, stix

Is there an easy way to get variants of `$v$` and `$w$` in using the stix package? I would like more "pointed" versions similar to the classic Times italic font.

Comment: are `$\textit{v}$` and `$\textit{w}$` easy enough for you?

Comment: If you are using xelatex or lualatex with `unicode-math` you could use `TeX Gyre Termes Math` as the mathematics font.  `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}` will give you more "pointy" v and w characters in math mode.

Comment: just be careful if you are using `\nu` in the same document.

Comment: @Thruston, I can't believe I didn't try that... great suggestion, very simple, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

run with `lualatex` or `xelatex`. The `v` and `w` are from times and the rest from stix

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={0118-0119}]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}   
\Huge
$u,v$ and $w,x$ % v,w from Times

\setmathfont{XITS Math}
$u,v$ and $w,x$ %  v,w from stix

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get with `newtxmath` from `$vw$`:

[image]

This is what I get with `stix`:

[image]

I'm not surprised you want to change them!

If you are not short of math groups, you can use the NewTX font for v and w:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}

\DeclareSymbolFont{txletters}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{txletters}{bold}{OML}{ntxmi}{b}{it}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{txletters}{`v}
\DeclareMathSymbol{w}{\mathalpha}{txletters}{`w}

\begin{document}
$avwz$
\end{document}
```

[image]

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and `unicode-math` it's even easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX}
\setmathfont{STIX Math}
\setmathfont[range={`v,`w}]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}
$avwz$
\end{document}
```

[image]